# Passing request from server to client

Tags: java, http

I need to pass response from server to clinet (a'la proxy):

```
 private void pushProxyToClient(HttpExchange httpExchange, HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {

            // pass headers
    Headers respHeaders = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = connection.getHeaderFields();
    for (String key: headers.keySet()) {

        if (key == null){
            continue;
        }

        List<String> values = headers.get(key);

        respHeaders.put(key, values);
    }

    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(connection.getResponseCode(), connection.getContentLength());

    // pass body
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
    OutputStreamWriter isw = new OutputStreamWriter(httpExchange.getResponseBody());

    long count = 0;
    while (count < connection.getContentLengthLong()) {
        isw.write(isr.read());
        count += 1;
    }

  isr.close();
  isw.close();
}
```

Unfortunatley, the client (firefox) tries to download response as file instead of render it as html. What I'm doing wrong?

### UPDATE

It's now working (*sendResponseHeaders* was invoked too early) but now I'm getting error (from browser) that it was unable to uncompress body.

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Content body is empty. Why?

### UPDATE 2

It almost works. The problem was **InputStreamWriter**. Changing it to `InputStream`'s read helped. Any way... some of pages render its content twice.. do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set content type? You content type should be same (for example text/html) and not like application/octet-stream. Hardcoded example:

```
Headers headers = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

In your example you set:

```
httpExchange.setAttribute(key, this.flatRequestValues(values));
```

instead of headers.add. Try:

```
Headers headers = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
for (String value: values) {
    headers.add(key, value);
}
```

EDIT: [or better](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/Headers.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%29):

```
Headers headers = httpExchange.getResponseHeaders();
headers.put(key, values);
```

Comment: no, it didn't help. The problem was.. `httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(connection.getResponseCode(), connection.getContentLength());` - it was to early! Unfortunately, browser says that compression of request body is unknown..

Comment: Look at headers and content, not what browser say. Under linux you can try www-perl: GET -Ssed http://lolcathost/ or developer tools in browser.

Comment: Hmm content body is empty.